# How to remove the last column border written in php?

Tags: php, html-table

I have the following code for the output:

```
        <?php
            function HailstoneNumbers($x){
                echo '<tbody>';
                static $c=0;
                echo '<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-width: medium;"> <tr:last-child style="border-bottom:0;">';
                echo '<td>'.$c.'</td>'.'<td>'.$x.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                if ($x == 1 && $c == 0){
                    // N is initially 1.
                    return $c;
                    }
                else if ($x == 1 && $c != 0){
                    // N is reduced to 1.
                    $c++;
                    }
                else if ($x % 2 == 0){
                    // If N is Even.
                    $c++;
                    HailstoneNumbers((int)($x / 2));
                    }
                else if ($x % 2 != 0){
                    // N is Odd.
                    $c++;
                    HailstoneNumbers(3 * $x + 1);
                    }
                return $c;
                }
            $x = $_GET['x'];
            if(isset($_GET['x'])){
                echo '<table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-width:medium;">
                <thead>
                <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-width:medium;">
                <th>Iteration</th><th>x</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>';
                HailstoneNumbers($x);
                echo '</tbody>'.'</table>';
            }
        ?>
```

[image]

But I want the table that looks something like:

[image]

I want border between columns in header and entries, and bottom borders on all rows except for the last row. However, I am stuck on how to do that in php file without writing a css file.

Comment: You could change it so that the rows only have a top border, also miss the border on the title.

Comment: Unrelated: `$x = $_GET['x']; if(isset($_GET['x'])){` Check _before_ you assign

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS property "border-style:hidden" on table and instead of applying CSS on TR or TH tag you can apply CSS directly on TD, something like:

https://jsfiddle.net/kht8mnLc/6/

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-width:medium; border-style:hidden;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th style="border:1px solid black;">Iteration</th>
         <th style="border:1px solid black;">x</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid black;">aaa</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid black;">bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid black;">aaa</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid black;">bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid black;">aaa</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid black;">bbb</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```